# Mpegts packet corrupt with ffmpeg concat protocol

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use the `concat protocol` in ffmpeg as described in the ffmpeg docs:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

However I'm getting lots of errors about corrupt packets when running the concat, so I'm worried that this isn't the best approach. My actual use case will involve running unsupervised with a ton of different source videos, so I want to be sure that it's solid.

The `concat demuxer` approach succeeds without errors but takes about 10 times as long.

### Steps to reproduce

Download Big Buck Bunny:

```
wget https://download.blender.org/demo/movies/BBB/bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4
```

Transcode a 30 second chunk:

```
ffmpeg -i bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4 -ss '00:06:30' -t 30 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 bbb30.mp4
```

Create one second parts:

```
mkdir -p parts;
for i in $(seq -f "%02g" 0 29); do \
  ffmpeg \
    -i bbb30.mp4 \
    -ss "00:00:$i" -t 1 \
    -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 18 \
    -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb \
    -f mpegts \
    -y parts/$i.ts;
done
```

Combine all the parts into a new output mp4:

```
ffmpeg -y \
  -i "concat:parts/00.ts|parts/01.ts|parts/02.ts|parts/03.ts|parts/04.ts|parts/05.ts|parts/06.ts|parts/07.ts|parts/08.ts|parts/09.ts|parts/10.ts|parts/11.ts|parts/12.ts|parts/13.ts|parts/14.ts|parts/15.ts|parts/16.ts|parts/17.ts|parts/18.ts|parts/19.ts|parts/20.ts|parts/21.ts|parts/22.ts|parts/23.ts|parts/24.ts|parts/25.ts|parts/26.ts|parts/27.ts|parts/28.ts|parts/29.ts" \
  -c copy \
  output.mp4
```

Stderr has lots of warnings about corrupt packets (in this case always at dts = 21300):

```
[mpegts @ 0x555d172daa00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 213000).
concat:parts/00.ts|parts/01.ts|parts/02.ts|parts/03.ts|parts/04.ts|parts/05.ts|parts/06.ts|parts/07.ts|parts/08.ts|parts/09.ts|parts/10.ts|parts/11.ts|parts/12.ts|parts/13.ts|parts/14.ts|parts/15.ts|parts/16.ts|parts/17.ts|parts/18.ts|parts/19.ts|parts/20.ts|parts/21.ts|parts/22.ts|parts/23.ts|parts/24.ts|parts/25.ts|parts/26.ts|parts/27.ts|parts/28.ts|parts/29.ts: corrupt input packet in stream 0
```

The resulting mp4 looks ok to my eye, but obviously ffmpeg isn't happy about something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore these warnings.

Packets in a MPEG-TS container have a counter field which increments with each packet. These are expected to be continuous. Since you encoded your TS files in separate instances, that counter will start with 0 when switching from one TS input to another. But this has no salience in this use case. This happens with the concat protocol because a single TS demuxer instance is used to read all inputs as an amalgamated whole. The concat demuxer open a fresh TS demuxer for each input and then stitches all packets as a single stream.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Is there any risk using the concat protocol in this way vs the concat demuxer, in terms of playback compatibility?

Comment: No, not with TS files.

Comment: Yes, you get an invalid MPEG-TS with lots of errors and discontinuities and invalid timing. Even if players might cope it's still not a clean approach and you might end up with sync issues after you combine enough segments. The lightweight alternative is to use something like Videolan's multicat tool which is able to rebuild the stream's clock and restamp packets.

Comment: FFmpeg will try to repair your input but if you plan to do something with the TS then on software only you might be able to get away with it but if there's some hardware down the line you're asking for trouble (source: made software server to broadcast over satellite links)

Comment: In the user's workflow, ffmpeg will streamline packet timings when the new packet ts regresses back to 0 (or 1.4s here). Only with -copyts and forward jumps does ffmpeg retain input ts. Even that can be addressed with dts_delta_threshold.